# Filter shared query results with another panel in Grafana

Tags: grafana

Is it possible to filter the [data shared between panels in Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/share-query/)?

Let's say I would query all the columns in the first panel with:

`SELECT time, A, B, C, D FROM "table"`

And in a second panel, I would like to show only `A` end `B`, how can I filter that columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add transformation (e. g. Organize fields) and hide fields, which you don't need - it is not a "filtering", but field hiding.